# Google event email not displaying action card?

Tags: email, gmail, html-email, google-schemas

I have the following markup for an email:

```
            <html>

        <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Event",
  "name": "Taco Night",
  "startDate": "2015-04-18T15:30:00Z",
  "endDate": "2015-04-18T16:30:00Z",
  "location": {
    "@type": "Place",
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "name": "Google",
      "streetAddress": "24 Willie Mays Plaza",
      "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
      "addressRegion": "CA",
      "postalCode": "94107",
      "addressCountry": "USA"
    }
  },
  "potentialAction": [
    {
      "@type": "RsvpAction",
      "handler": {
        "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
        "url": "http://example.com/rsvp?eventId=123&value=yes"
      },
      "attendance": "http://schema.org/RsvpAttendance/Yes"
    },
    {
      "@type": "RsvpAction",
      "handler": {
        "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
        "url": "http://example.com/rsvp?eventId=123&value=no"
      },
      "attendance": "http://schema.org/RsvpAttendance/No"
    },
    {
      "@type": "RsvpAction",
      "handler": {
        "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
        "url": "http://example.com/rsvp?eventId=123&value=maybe"
      },
      "attendance": "http://schema.org/RsvpAttendance/Maybe"
    }
  ]
}
</script>

          <body>
            HI
          </body>
        </html>
```

But, when I use their email markup test tool, I get just a plain text email that has nothing in it but 'HI'. How do I get that google card with the agenda and the Yes, No, Maybe buttons for events?

Answer (score 0):

**How do I get that google card with the agenda and the Yes, No, Maybe buttons for events?**

> A
>   [RsvpAction](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/rsvp-action)
>   can be used for responding to an event invitation from inside the
>   inbox. The inbox renders this action by showing the details of the
>   event and a combination of Yes/No/Maybe responses defined by the
>   sender.

Check the official [Email Markup guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/actions-overview) for more info.